# Asymptotic series solution to a transcendental matrix equation with a small parameter

Tags: asymptotics, matrix-equations, hyperbolic-functions, perturbation-theory, transcendental-equations

I have the following equation, where $X$ is a matrix, $f$ is a linear function of matrices, and $0<\varepsilon\ll1$:

$$X=\frac{Xf(X)}{\varepsilon}+\tanh\left(\frac{Xf(X)}{\varepsilon}\right)$$

I've tried an asymptotic expansion of the form:

$$X=X_0+\varepsilon X_1+\varepsilon^2 X_2+\cdots$$

but I'm not sure how to expand $\tanh$ in terms of powers of $\varepsilon$. If $X=O(1)$ then $\frac{Xf(X)}{\varepsilon}$ is very large and I'm not sure of the series representation of $\tanh$ can be used.

Comment: You can use long division to divide the power series for $\sinh$ by the one for $\cosh.$ That may not lead you to discover the general pattern, but possibly you need only the first few terms.

Comment: Your equation might not make sense if $X=O(1)$.  Intuitively, $\tanh=O(1)$ (and literally if your matrices are $1\times 1$), so the equation seems to imply $X=Xf(X)/\epsilon+O(1)=O(1/\epsilon)$.

Comment: @Michael I think this arrives at the same issues as when trying to use the power series for $\tanh$.

Comment: @user254433 $f(X)$ can be 0, even if $X=O(1)$.

Comment: You could try it with $X_0 = 0$, so $X = O(\epsilon)$.